# gmaps4rails and autocomplete google place API incompatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I've a problem of compatibility between gmaps4rails gem and google place API

Basically if I put in my view a gmpas4rails  like this:

```
<%=gmaps%>
```

then this script doesnt work anymore (it normaly activate an autocomplete on user_address field:

```
 $(document).ready(initialize_gmaps_autocomplete_user_address());

function initialize_gmaps_autocomplete_user_address() {
var input = document.getElementById('user_address');
var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(42.71422,-4.222666), new google.maps.LatLng(51.179343,8.47412));
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.setBounds(defaultBounds);
autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
}
```

I've tried to call the script by gmaps4rails.call_back and to change the var names in my scripts...

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you make a second call to the google api which mess things up.

Two solutions here:

1) don't include the js from the partial:

```
<%= gmaps({your_hash}, true, false) %>
```

And include all the js files manually but be sure to write:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry,places"></script>
```

[Here is the original partial](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/app/views/gmaps4rails/_gmaps4rails.html.erb) so you don't forget any file.

2) Grab the current version on git and add `places` directly:

```
<%= gmaps({ "map_options" => { "libraries" => ["places"] } }) %>
```

I'll update the gem later, so versions above `0.10.2` will have this included.

Comment: OK i'll wait for the next version so, my app isn't ready to deploy yet

Comment: the one from github is fine if you can't wait. You'll even see that your code is inside the test app bundled in the gem: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/blob/master/test/dummy/app/views/users/index.html.erb

Comment: For 1.5.6 in my case first solution looks like
    <%= gmaps(
            map_options: ...,
            polylines: ...,
            scripts: :none
    )  %>

Answer (score 1):

Actually 2) should be

```
<%= gmaps({:map_options => {:libraries => ["places"]}}) %>
```

because in the source code of gmaps4rails symbols are used instead of strings.

To make it work with strings you'd have to use HashWithIndifferentAccess:

```
<%= gmaps(HashWithIndifferentAccess.new("map_options" => {"libraries" => ['places']}))%>
```