# How implement Gmaps4rails and autocomplete

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, gmaps4rails

I really disapointed, I trying to implement autocomplete on my app but I don't know how can do that. I searched on Google, StackOverflow but I can't find something to understand... I want autocomplete only for France.

So I trying this but this code don't work

My view (script and form)

```
<%= form_tag(result_path, method: :get) %>
<%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class:"search-query form-control", placeholder:"Ex: Corse, Arcachon..."  %>
<%= submit_tag "Partez", class:"btn btn-danger", name: nil %>
<script>
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
handler.fitMapToBounds();

});
 $(document).ready(initialize_gmaps_autocomplete_user_address());

function initialize_gmaps_autocomplete_user_address() {
var input = document.getElementById('query');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
autocomplete.setTypes(['geocode']);
}
</script>
```

Controller

```
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@campings) do |camping, marker|
        marker.lat camping.latitude
        marker.lng camping.longitude
        marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/campings/infowindow", :locals => { :camping => camping})
        marker.picture ({
          "url" => "http://avantjetaisriche.com/map-pin.png",
          "width" =>  29,
          "height" => 32})
```

My application.js

```
/= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= validyoutube
//= require_tree .
```

Can you help me ? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To help you start with the implementation, you may try going through these helpful GitHub posts:

- [A Ruby wrapper around the Google Places API](https://github.com/qpowell/google_places)
- [Google Maps v3 search with jQuery UI Autocomplete, ready for use with Rails asset pipeline](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/gmaps-autocomplete-rails)

Additionally, please also try going through [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete) wherein it was mentioned that a Place Autocomplete request is an HTTP URL of the following from:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/output?parameters
```

And, to set it to your preferred language, please add `language` parameter into your request with value equal to the language code of your choice. Please see [list of supported languages](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport) and their codes.

You may also check solution given in [gmaps4rails with Google Maps searchbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809673/gmaps4rails-with-google-maps-searchbox) and see if it helps.